# I need to count the right amount of discount with the right country, how do i do this?

Tags: t-sql, count

this is the code i have atm:

```
SELECT Discount,
       country,
       count(country) AS total
FROM   OrderDetails,
       Customers
WHERE  discount != 0
GROUP  BY Discount,
          country
HAVING ( count(country) > 0 )
ORDER  BY discount DESC
```

what i need to do now, and can't find anywhere, is to have the count(country) add up with the right Discount numbers. That way i know how much discount each country has gotten.
I have looked everywhere and i can't find anything. Even in my own papers i got from school.

so this is the code with the join, so it's a little more clear to look at:

```
select Discount, country, count(country) as total
from Orders O
join Customers C
on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
join OrderDetails OD
on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID
where discount != 0
group by Discount, country
having (count(country)>0)
order by discount DESC
```

Comment: `from OrderDetails, Customers` is certainly wrong. You are missing a join condition.

Comment: ok. but then i have to add useless tables in it.

Comment: They aren't useless if they are giving you correct results. I imagine the linkage is `Customers -> OrderHeader -> OrderDetails`

Comment: but the thing i have now, the original one works perfectly fine too. i'll try it out with the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.country, sum(od.discount)   as totalDiscount
from orders o
inner join customers c
on c.customerID = o.customerID
inner join orderDetails od
on od.orderID = o.orderID
where od.discount != 0
group by c.country
order by sum(od.discount) desc
```